# Parallel makefile execution causes a library to be built twice

Tags: makefile

I have two binaries (bin_a, bin_b) and a library (lib) shared by these two binaries.
The binaries depend on the library.

main makefile:

```
include makeenv.mk

all: $(BIN_A) $(BIN_B)

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    $(MAKE) -C lib clean
    $(MAKE) -C bin_a clean
    $(MAKE) -C bin_b clean
```

makeenv.mk:

```
BIN_A=$(ROOT)/bin_a/bin_a
BIN_B=$(ROOT)/bin_b/bin_b
LIB=$(ROOT)/lib/liblib.so

first_target: all

$(BIN_A):
    $(MAKE) -C $(ROOT)/bin_a

$(BIN_B):
    $(MAKE) -C $(ROOT)/bin_b

$(LIB):
    $(MAKE) -C $(ROOT)/lib
```

bin_a/makefile:

```
include ../makeenv.mk

all: bin_a

bin_a: $(LIB)
    gcc -I $(ROOT) -L $(ROOT)/lib -l lib -o $@ bin_a.c

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -f bin_a
```

bin_b/makefile:

```
include ../makeenv.mk

all: bin_b

bin_b: $(LIB)
    gcc -I $(ROOT) -L $(ROOT)/lib -l lib -o $@ bin_b.c

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -f bin_b
```

lib/makefile:

```
include ../makeenv.mk

TARGET=liblib.so

all: $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): lib.c
    gcc -shared -fPIC -o $@ $^
    sleep 5

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -f liblib.so
```

If I type make, everything is built just fine:

```
make -C /tmp/mak/bin_a
make[1]: Entering directory `/tmp/mak/bin_a'
make -C /tmp/mak/lib
make[2]: Entering directory `/tmp/mak/lib'
gcc -shared -fPIC -o liblib.so lib.c
sleep 5
make[2]: Leaving directory `/tmp/mak/lib'
gcc -I /tmp/mak -L /tmp/mak/lib -l lib -o bin_a bin_a.c
make[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/mak/bin_a'
make -C /tmp/mak/bin_b
make[1]: Entering directory `/tmp/mak/bin_b'
gcc -I /tmp/mak -L /tmp/mak/lib -l lib -o bin_b bin_b.c
make[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/mak/bin_b'
```

However if I want to build it parallely, the library is built twice:

```
make -C /tmp/mak/bin_a
make -C /tmp/mak/bin_b
make[1]: Entering directory `/tmp/mak/bin_a'
make -C /tmp/mak/lib
make[1]: Entering directory `/tmp/mak/bin_b'
make -C /tmp/mak/lib
make[2]: Entering directory `/tmp/mak/lib'
gcc -shared -fPIC -o liblib.so lib.c
make[2]: Entering directory `/tmp/mak/lib'
gcc -shared -fPIC -o liblib.so lib.c
sleep 5
sleep 5
make[2]: Leaving directory `/tmp/mak/lib'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/tmp/mak/lib'
gcc -I /tmp/mak -L /tmp/mak/lib -l lib -o bin_a bin_a.c
gcc -I /tmp/mak -L /tmp/mak/lib -l lib -o bin_b bin_b.c
make[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/mak/bin_a'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/mak/bin_b'
```

The question is: why?

And how to fix these makefiles to make the parallel run work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The toplevel makefile doesn't know that the sub-makefiles are going to each build `$(LIB)` and the sub-makefiles, naturally, don't know anything about what the other makefile is doing.

So you have a race condition wherein they both detect that `$(LIB)` needs to be rebuilt and then both schedule it for building. This is one of the main arguments in the [Recursive Make Considered Harmful (pdf)](http://aegis.sourceforge.net/auug97.pdf) paper.

Changing `makeenv.mk` to read:

```
BIN_A=$(ROOT)/bin_a/bin_a
BIN_B=$(ROOT)/bin_b/bin_b
LIB=$(ROOT)/lib/liblib.so

first_target: all

$(BIN_A): $(LIB)
    $(MAKE) -C $(ROOT)/bin_a

$(BIN_B): $(LIB)
    $(MAKE) -C $(ROOT)/bin_b

$(LIB):
    $(MAKE) -C $(ROOT)/lib
```

might do enough to get you what you want in this case (but I would have to try it and examine the prereq listings a bit more carefully to be sure).

Alternatively, you could read the paper I listed before and stop using recursive make for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
subdirs=lib bin_a bin_b
.PHONY : all $(subdirs)

bin_a bin_b : lib

$(subdirs) : 
    $(MAKE) -C $@ $(MAKECMDGOALS)
```

This worked for me.
Alternatively I have tried

```
all : makeall

bin_a bin_b : lib

makeall :
   $(MAKE) -C lib
   $(MAKE) -C bin_a 
   $(MAKE) -C bin_b 
   $(MAKE) -C moredirs
```

In my hands, the difficulty is to to both parallel and keep the make process in a defined sequence.  If you have a large project you cannot wait to do single-threaded make.  You almost have to do make -j 24.
Let me know if there is any improvement in this.